# Getting CORS issue in API calling from AJAX

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, spring-boot, content-security-policy

I am getting CORS issue while calling API from Ajax with header `Content-Security-Policy":"frame-ancestors 'none'`.

My APIs are built in Java spring boot. API server is already configured with `Access-Control-Allow-Origin : *`. If i remove `Content-Security-Policy":"frame-ancestors 'none'`, the API is working perfectly fine.

Below is request :

```
$.ajax({url: "https://****.com/api/v2/login",
    type: 'post',
    data: JSON.stringify(domain),
    headers: {
      "x-dreamfactory-api-key":'*******',
      "x-frame-options":'deny',
      "Content-Security-Policy":"frame-ancestors 'none'",
      "pragma":'no-cache',
      "sec-fetch-mode":'cors',
      "Referer":'https://****.com',
      "origin":'https://****.com',
      "sec-fetch-site":'same-site',
      "sec-fetch-dest":'empty',
      "Content-Type":'application/json'
    },
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
    }
  });
```

My API configuration using `WebMVCConfigurationSupport` below :

```
@Override

public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {

registry.addMapping("/v2/**").allowedMethods("PATCH","GET", "POST", "OPTIONS","PUT", "DELETE").allowedOrigins("*")
.allowedHeaders("*").allowCredentials(true);
}
```

Comment: please provide some more code samples(the class that extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter , the controller .etc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Content-Security-Policy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy) is a **response** header:

> The HTTP Content-Security-Policy response header allows website
> administrators to control resources the user agent is allowed to load
> for a given page.

So it makes no sense to send it in an AJAX request.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But if it does not make any sense then why it is affecting the response?

Comment: Please, consider review the response you are actually receiving in your browser, probably Spring Boot is returning some kind of error upon the reception of the `Content-Security-Header` header, probably a white label page or something similar: that may be causing your CORS issue (the server is returning an inappropriate resource for your JQuery AJAX request).

The reason could be the one exposed by @Olivier in the answer, there is no need to include the header in your request, it is a response header that should be provided by the server.